# Kubernetes initContainers to copy file and execute

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a situation where we will have list of IP addresses (which are coming from the config map) then we need to validate these IP Addresses (i.e. check if they are accessible from this machine) then return the first accessible IP address so that application can access this ip address to process further actions.

I got the know that we can use **InitContainers** to do this stuff. But my question is how can we run a shell script in the initcontainer to identify the accessible IP Address and  set it in the Environmental variable so that application process this further.

Answer (score 2):

`InitContainers` can communicate with other, normal containers through `volumes`.
You can use `emptyDir` `volume` type, which is a directory that allows the `pod` to store data for the duration of its life cycle.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-name
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: addresses
    emptyDir: {}
  initContainers:
  - name: ip-selector
    image: your-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: addresses
      mountPath: /path/to/ip/addresses
  containers:
  - name: ip-handler
    image: your-image
    volumeMounts:
    - name: addresses
      mountPath: /path/to/ip/addresses/handler
      readOnly: true # optional
```

Your `initContainer` can now save .env file with addresses in `/path/to/ip/addresses` path and then your normal container can read this file from `/path/to/ip/addresses/handler` path.

Comment: Thanks. So where can we put the my shell script which can be invoked in the initContainer to get the accessible Ip Address. 
`initContainers:
       - name: wait-for-ip
         image: image

         env:
         - name: listofips
           valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: config-map
              key: listofIps

`
Here is my sample initcontainer code

Answer (score 0):

**Option : 1**

Once you get the IP inside the init container you can create the secret with value and use it.

```
initContainers:
        - name: secret
          image: gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl:latest
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - kubectl create secret mysecret ... -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
      containers:
        - name: test-container
          image: image-uri:latest
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: mysecret
```

**Option : 2**

You can also use the **shared mount** option to write IP into the file, and inside the container, you can run the command to set the file contents to Env. So when your main container start it will start with the IP as Env.

```
command: [bash, -c, "source /tmp/env && service command"]
```

**Example**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: [bash, -c, "source /tmp/env && service command"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: /tmp/env
  initContainers:
  - name: ip-check
    image: busybox:1.28
    command:
    - Command or script to check the IP write to > /tmp/env
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: "/tmp"
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: workdir
    emptyDir: {}
```